# Gaussian Elimination Clarification

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Hello I am trying to understand my textbook and instructors algorithm for Gaussian Elimination

In class we perform the following steps

> Select smallest p such that $a_{p1}$ =/= 0
>   If P=/=1 Interchange rows $R_{1}$ and $R_{p}$
>   Perform elimination

What i dont understand is the first two steps
I understand that we find the first column element in the first column thats  non zero, but how do I make the comparison to know which row to switch with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first column is non-zero (otherwise move to the next column).

If the first entry is non-zero. You have completed that instruction.

Suppose not, if $p$-th entry is the first non-zero entry in the first column. Swap the  $p$-th row with the first row.